# Bind a List<string> to a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, ivalueconverter

After 20+ years of windows programming and two days of WPF I feel I know nothing :-)

My first WPF program is really simple: You drop a few files from explorer and their names are shown in a TextBox control.
(It works fine for a ListBox, but that isn't what I want. And of course adding the lines manually in the Drop event works as well - but I want to learn about the Binding ways..)

So I wrote a Converter but somehow it insn't used (breakpoints won't get hit) and nothing shows up.

It should be a small thing or maybe I'm totally off track. Found many examples for similar things from which i patched this together but still can't get it to work.

(I probably won't need the ConvertBack, but wrote it down anyway..)

Here is the converter class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpTest02
{
  public class ListToTextConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in (List<string>)value) sb.AppendLine(s);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string[] lines = ((string)value).Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return lines.ToList<String>();
        }
   }

}
```

The MainWindow.xaml, where I suspect the binding problem to be:

```
<Window x:Class="WpTest02.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpTest02"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ListToTextConverter x:Key="converter1" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid >
        <TextBox Name="tb_files" Margin="50,20,0,0"  AllowDrop="True" 
                 PreviewDragOver="tb_files_PreviewDragOver" Drop="tb_files_Drop" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=fileNames, Converter={StaticResource converter1} }"
                 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the Codebehind with nothing more the the data property to bind to and the drag&drop code, which works.

```
using System; 
//etc ..

namespace WpTest02
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fileNames = new List<string>();
        }


        public List<string> fileNames { get; set; }

        private void tb_files_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var files = ((DataObject)e.Data).GetFileDropList();
            foreach (string s in files) fileNames.Add(s);

            // EDIT: this doesn't help ? Wrong!                     
            // EDIT: this is actually necessary! :                     
            tb_files.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();

            // this obviosly would work:
            //foreach (string s in files) tb_files.Text += s + "\r\n";
        }

        private void tb_files_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
}
```

**Note**: I have editied the last piece of code to stress the importance of the `UpdateTarget` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataContext of the TextBox must be set to bind the data. Like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileNames = new List<string>();
        this.tb_files.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had this line in the original program. The one I posted was a stripped down version. But now that I have a working version I will be able to track down the probem(s) with the original code..

Answer (score 4):

For `Binding` to work you need to assign **`Window's DataContext`** to the instance where property resides which in your case is Window class itself.

So set DataContext in constructor and it should work fine:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fileNames = new List<string>();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

**OR**

You have to explicitly resolve the binding from XAML using **`ElementName`** in your binding:

```
<Window x:Name="myWindow">
  ....
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=fileNames, ElementName=myWindow,
                          Converter={StaticResource converter1}}"/>
```

For XAML approach to work, you have to initialize the list before XAML gets loaded i.e. before **`InitializeComponent`** gets called.

```
fileNames = new List<string>();
InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. So much to learn.. Simply adding it to the xaml throws a null object refrence error in the converter though. (The value is null upon program startup.) I can catch it but I wonder what's the reason for the different behaviour? I suspect the xaml is called earlier now?

Comment: I have updated the answer for your question. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

this is the general pattern which should work for you. Feel free to contact me with any questions. Best of luck! ~Justin

```
<Window xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourProject.YourViewModelNamespace"
        xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:YourProject.YourValueConverterNamespace">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vc:YourValueConverter x:key="YourValueConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:YourViewViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyItems, Converter={StaticResource YourValueConverter}}"/>
</Window>

public class YourViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<string> _myItems;
    ObservableCollection<string> MyItems
    {
        get { return _gameProfileListItems; }
        set { _gameProfileListItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyItems"); }
    }
    
    public void SetMyItems()
    {
        //    go and get your data here, transfer it to an observable collection
        //    and then assign it to this.GameProfileListItems (i would recommend writing a .ToObservableCollection() extension method for IEnumerable)
        this.MyItems = SomeManagerOrUtil.GetYourData().ToObservableCollection();
    }
}

public class YourView : Window
{
    YourViewViewModel ViewModel
    {
        { get return this.DataContext as YourViewViewModel; }
    }

    public void YourView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        this.ViewModel.SetMyItems();
    }
}
```